# malicious peers in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a quite theoretical question about the scheme used in Hyperledger Fabric for the developers.

If a chaincode has been made by malicious node and only endorse some of the malicious nodes. Then, if a client's transaction triggers this code, the malicious nodes could manipulate with their response. Let us assume that all the responses are 1 while it should be 0. Then, if the client somehow accept their responses, it will be send through the rest of the transaction flow and eventually end up in the ledger. Hence, this incorrect result will be in the ledger.

Would this ever happen? Or did I misunderstood some parts?

Answer (score 0):

For a theoretical question, the theoretical answer is no, it wouldn't happen. For a blockchain network, all peers on a channel that are involved in a transaction needs to have the same chaincode.

Also, even though a peer validates a transaction and sends those successful responses to the client. When the client submit these responses for the transaction to be committed, it will be validated by all peers involved in that transaction before being committed. Basically all parties are agreeing that this is correct at once.

If one node has a different value than all the other nodes do, then something is wrong.

You can follow this simplified explanation of the transaction flow here: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html, you can view especially step number 5.

Comment: I can understand how this is done with a classical blockchain structure, I don't get it when endorsers involved. As you also stated: "all peers on a channel that are involved in a transaction needs to have the same chaincode", what if all the involved peers are malicious? What would happened in that case? With the new privacy policy, the other peers can only validate whether the endorsers agreed with it, not the content of the transaction, or am I wrong?

Comment: If all your peers are "malicious" then its no longer your blockchain. :)